# Facing encryption

Tags: encryption

I have an encrypted hex string:

```
AA969CF9657F77C597C8EAFF1594D59374E4977F
```

which I know corresponds to the plaintext:

```
http://jogos.meo.pt/
```

I want to know if it is possible to find out what encryption algorithm might have been used?
Anybody could help me please?

Comment: [As I suggested on crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/facing-encryption#comment26965_12616), if you want anyone to be able to solve this, you should try to give more samples than just one. It _looks_ like this might be a very simple byte-wise additive Vigenère-type cipher, but it's hard to tell for sure from just a single short sample.

Comment: 40 characters? SHA1 perhaps? It's not a plain one (tried `echo -n 'http://jogos.meo.pt/'|sha1sum -` and `echo 'http://jogos.meo.pt/'|sha1sum -`) but could be salted. Too little info to tell. And aside from that probably off-topic in the sense that without associating this to a piece of software this is hardly reverse (code) engineering.

Comment: i have more samples like "93AA94" correspond to "nao".

Comment: "9AA696" correspond to "sim"

Comment: "92A094CE94A397F674FAE2" correspond to "meojogos.pt"

Comment: How do you know these data "correspond" to each other? Can you generate them at will? Where does this data come from? Knowing that might help finding out what the encryption is.

Comment: I´m doing analogy to one i have decoded.

Answer (score 4):

You'll likely need to reverse engineer the code that does the decryption. Tools such as [FindCrypt](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=27) and the Krypto Analyzer ("KANAL") plugin for [PEiD](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/PEiD) may help you with a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Partly repeating what I already wrote in [my comment at crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/facing-encryption#comment26973_12616)…

The one thing you can learn from that data is that the known ciphertext (20 bytes in hex-representation)

```
AA969CF9657F77C597C8EAFF1594D59374E4977F
```

can be XORed with the (let's just call it) OTP

```
C2E2E8895F5058AFF8AF858C3BF9B0FC5A94E350
```

to get the hex-encoded version of the known plaintext `http://jogos.meo.pt/` which is

```
687474703A2F2F6A6F676F732E6D656F2E70742F
```

As you don't know anything else, it's already hard to tell if an algorithm or an OTP was used. Is `C2E2E8895F5058AFF8AF858C3BF9B0FC5A94E350` an OTP or the result of a PRNG, a hash, or something else? You can't tell by simply looking at this rather minimal piece of information.

Therefore, the only chance you have is to collect enough samples that will allow you to recognize a specific pattern. Yet, chances are that that pattern boils down to being a random OTP string of who-knows-what length. Personally, I can't *“feel”* any patterns by just looking at it… but you could check the obvious ones: keyed Vignere over a 256 byte base, etc.

Comment: @user36384: apologies. I think the markdown used on this site removes the prefix. Use backticks `\`xxx\`` to indicate literal text.

Comment: ok i´m sorry. I´m gonna correct "AA969CF9657F77FEA9F4D3F5CA96E17099E27F" correspond to "xxxxxxxmeojogos.pt/" xxxxxxx correspond to http://

Answer (score 1):

Your ciphertext consists of 40 hexadecimal digits, which encode 20 bytes.  Your plaintext is 20 ASCII characters long.  The obvious assumption, therefore, is that the ciphertext has been calculated by taking the ASCII code of each plaintext character and either adding (modulo 256) or XORing a corresponding key byte with it.

Furthermore, the bytes in your ciphertext are not uniformly distributed over the range from 0 to 255, suggesting that what you have is *not* a secure [stream cipher](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) but something weaker.

Indeed, taking each byte of the ciphertext and subtracting the corresponding byte of plaintext yields:

```
42 22 28 89 2b 50 48 5b 28 61 7b 8c e7 27 70 24 46 74 23 50
```

or, in ASCII (using `\xHH` for characters outside the valid ASCII range):

```
B"(\x89+PH[(a{\x8C\xE7'p$Ft#P
```

Those extra characters might belong to some 8-bit extension of ASCII, such as [Windows-1252](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which would make the "keystream" look like this:

```
B"(‰+PH[(a{Œç'p$Ft#P
```

This looks plausibly like something someone might produce simply by mashing "random" keys on a non-English keyboard, so it's at least plausible that the "encryption" mightsimply consist of adding this key string to the plaintext byte by byte.  However, without more samples, there's no real way to confirm this.

Comment: "526FB829999FABF1A3F6DEFFDA4CD39BA93CA79F9A98B82D92A794F6BB2AFCC0F2AED9BF4DE2AB929890A0CBAA95BB2297F9E2C1F2BA319BA3E7977CAA9696F3" correspond to "C:\Programas\SiteKiosk\Skins\Public\Startpages\Portal\Start.html"

Comment: My objective is to find out what is this "7E6E7E1D63".

Comment: Are you sure about the "Startpages"? I can't decode the cipher entirely (yet), but just looking at the message length and the high two bits of each byte suggests that it should be replaced by something 13 characters long (rather than 10), and possibly with something other than lowercase letters in the middle.

Comment: i´m sorry, but you can explain to me how you conclude that?

Comment: another sample "AA969CF9657F77FEA9F4D3F5CA96E17099E27FA690A294FD779DA9FC74FAE215CE95DBAD8509A597929A" correspond to "xxxxxxxmeojogos.pt/jogos.meo.pt/index.html" xxxxxxx equal to http://

Comment: I have discovered this password "XupaMos". Could it be the string to add to the plaintext??